# Is null really special or not?

Tags: java, casting, null

As per [JLS 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) :

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null
>   (§3.10.7, §15.8.1), which has no name.
>
> Because the null type has no name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
>
> The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
>   type.
>
> The null reference can always undergo a widening reference conversion
>   to any reference type.
>
> In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend
>   that **null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type.**

If null could really be of any reference type then why IS-A test fails?
i.e.

```
null instanceof Object      //returns false
```

OR

```
null instanceof String      //returns false
```

Comment: `instanceof` returns `false` if its first operand is `null`, always.

Comment: In your examples, null could be of any type. I'm not entirely sure, but if you change them to `(Object)null instanceof Object` and `(String)null instanceof String` or `Object o = null; o instanceof Object` and `String s = null; s instanceof String` it should return true.

Comment: It was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336608/what-does-null-mean/19336626#19336626

Comment: `null`  isn't even an instance, it's specifically the lack of an instance. So why would it be an instance of anything?

Comment: This might prove to be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java  similar like this

Comment: `null` isn't really an _instance_ of a type, though it can be assigned to references of that type.

Comment: @Kevin As per JLS widening is always possible with null. Then why it would not widen (without doing it explicitly) and return true in this expression itself `null instanceof Object` ?

Comment: @maximus335 Because null in `null instanceof Object` isn't a reference type. For example, when we have `Object o = new String("test");`, `Object` is the reference type and `String` is the object type. In your example, null is lacking a reference type, so therefore the `instanceof` will always fail. (At least that's how I've learned it.) I would also suggest in reading the post in the link @Stultuske provided.

Comment: @kevin I just tried running code from your previous comment i.e.   `(String)null instanceof String` it returns false not true. Please correct it.

Comment: @maximus335 Ah, I stand corrected. It turns out null will always return false, so I learned something new myself thanks to your question. `String s = null; s instanceof String` also returns false so it seems ([ideone test](http://ideone.com/dGJRcC)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `null` as the *exact opposite* of `Object` . Any value can be assigned to an Object, likewise any reference type can be set to `null`. `instanceof` is always true if RHS is `Object`, likewise `instanceof` is always false if `null` is the LHS. Logically, if a language has a structure which is *everything* (Object), it should also have a structure to define *nothing* (null).

Now, coming back to your original question. In java, suppose you have

`Object o = null`, its equivalent byte code instruction will be.

```
0: aconst_null --> Null reference is pushed onto the stack
1: astore_1    --> store a reference into local variable 1 (i.e, Object o)
```

So *under the hood* `null` is handled in a *different* way. 
`System.out.println(null instanceof Object);` will give false because according to the semantics of the language `null` is *nothing* and cannot have any instance. It is a mere placeholder to represent that a *reference* points to a *valid but junk value*.

Answer (score 1):

`object instanceof Type` checks the *runtime type of the object referred to by the reference* `object`.  For example,

```
 Animal animal = new Dog();
 animal instanceof Dog; // returns true
```

`instanceof` looks up the actual object referred to by the reference and tests its runtime type.  `null` does not refer to an actual object on the heap, so of course `null instanceof Type` has to return false.